# Android Map : How to cutomize Marker icon with SVG file?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have a SGV icon (.svg) that I want to use like cutom icon for map markers.

How should I proceed ? I didn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: You probably first need to create a "vector asset" from the SVG file [as instructed in Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#running).

Answer (score 1):

If the SVG is part of your resources, you could simply add it to MarkerOptions by calling

```
val svgIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_svg_name_here)
val marker = MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(latitude, longitude)).icon(svgIcon)
googleMap?.addMarker(marker)
```

If it isn't in your resources, just use another method of the `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

Comment: I actually did, but it is not recognized like a valid file extension for drawable folder (accept only .png or .xml)

Comment: You could import the svg as a XML-drawable (just right-click on resurces folder and add new vector asset)

Comment: You can't use vector images as map markers as far as I know. The BitmapDescriptorFactory, as its name suggests, only supports bitmaps.